# Flat root spline vs filet root spline: what's the difference

Tags: mechanical-engineering, meshing

I'm looking at a hobby micro servo, which has a 5mm splined shaft output. Specifically, this is a Tower Pro model SG90 or clone.  Close-up photos of the shaft below.

I've found online diagrams for both a 30 degree Flat Root Spline shaft, and a 30 degree Filet Root Spline.   Can someone please explain the difference between these spline designs?

[image: Micrograph of splned output shaft]

[image: Closeup of spline teeth]

I'm adding a drawing approximating the photos (and a hub) of a 21 tooth spline with a 5mm pitch circle and 45 degree pressure angle.  (To simplify, I've not used involute teeth.)

I have filleted the exposed corners of the teeth at 0.06 mm.  Is it these that make it a fillet root spline?

I've also added a fillet to the empty spaces joining the faces.

[image: detail drawing of spline]

P.S.  here's a link to my [in-progress CAD model](https://cad.onshape.com/documents/ca0cae54ca707e3d00ffdb59/w/b70f9fe24bf5ee92396a8648/e/f0e98e690a99cf50ba90bc92).   Feedback welome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fillet root splines have a smooth curve between adjacent teeth and the root diameter, flat root splines may not and will have a flat portion of tooth space between teeth. Fillet root teeth provide better bending strength and thus higher load capacity.

The spline in your picture appears to be a fillet root, although the pressure angle looks a lot higher than 30 degrees.

Comment: Thanks.  I certainly agree the servo spline looks like a fillet, and I'm guessing its a 45 degree pressure angle.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by the "root diameter", I've updated my question with a diagram to help clarify what I'm asking.

Comment: The root diameter in splines and gears is the diameter to the bottom of the teeth.

Comment: Thanks.   I managed to get a look at the ISO spec for exact definitions, but I understand yours better now.

Answer (score 1):

According to ISO 4156-1:2005, the following definitions apply:

> 3.6
> fillet root spline
>
> spline having a tooth or space profile in which the opposing flanks are connected to the root circle (D<sub>ei</sub> or D<sub>ie</sub>) by a ***single*** fillet.
>
> 3.7 flat root spline
>
> spline having a tooth or space profile in which ***each*** the opposing flanks are connected to the root circle (D<sub>ei</sub> or D<sub>ie</sub>) by a fillet.

[emphasis added]

The distinction is quite subtle, as even flat root splines have fillets.

From what I now understand, the photos in my question are fillet root splines.  However, the diagram is sort of a hybrid.  I'll try to draw a second diagram to illustrate the difference and add it here.